# Is there a dictionary or summary for all the code commands in Unity 2019.2.11f1?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This sounds very weird, so let me explain in detail:

The way I work in Unity, is I think of what I need to do (such as make a climbing script) then I go
to YouTube or Google to look for a tutorial, but sometimes there's issues with using that code for
any particular reason. All I do is essentially monkey see, monkey do, but I want to start writing code myself instead of relying on a teacher in a video that may or may not reply to questions.

I have gone to the Unity manual and had a look through a lot, but it doesn't show the actual code/command, just explaining general terms for functions in Unity but not the code itself.

I am self-taught and instead of solely relying on videos, I want to just reference from a sort of code-dictionary/summary and figure it out myself. I have spent ages trying to find something like this, but
for the life of me, I cannot find what I need.

I don't know if there's a hidden sub-section of Unity's manual, or if it's solely for explaining terms without showing just the code.

For example, let's say you go to a library and you want to learn Latin, so you go in looking for a translation dictionary, but instead, everything there talks about the history and behaviour of that language, everything except the translation and terminology.

I have tried going by memory and searching when trying to make my own script, but it would make it infinitely easier if there was a summary of all the commands. There should be something like that, that already exists and I think I'm just having an absolute brain-fart over this.

Can anyone help out?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/index.html

Comment: It could be useful to work through an online course/tutorial - some free ones are available [here](https://learn.unity.com/tutorials/?k=%5B%22lang%3Aen%22%2C%22prm%3Anone_premium%22%5D&ob=starts). It takes time to learn to write your own code. Coding is a skill just like swimming, so you need lessons and practice. Build up from the basics. Some stuff might seem easy at the beginning. As you progress, you will be relying on things you learned in the past to come up with solutions to new coding problems. Skip past anything like history, etc. so you can focus on the coding portions.

Comment: @Poosh The problem is, this is the same as watching tutorial videos on YouTube. I want to reference from a list of commands, but I don't know where to find the summary of them all, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You talked about the Unity Manual. You were almost there! There's also a [Unity scripting API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/). It shows every bits of code you can use in the unity Engine. There's a lot of coding examples on what the scripting components do.

Comment: This was partially useful, but it missed some of the most basic components, such as movement like translate, velocity, transform, etc, otherwise it almost has what I need, thank you so much for this :D

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

Comment: Thank you, this is insanely helpful! :D